# How to merge two different subnet networks

Tags: network-shares, subnet

```
           Network A                                   Network  B

      PC1                PC2                     PC3                PC4         
(192.168.1.100)    (192.168.1.101)         (192.168.0.100)    (192.168.0.101)
       |                  |                       |                  |
    --------------------------                ----------------------------
                |                                           |
             Router A ---------------------------------  Router B
          (192.168.1.1)                                (192.168.0.1)
          255.255.255.0                                255.255.255.0
                |                                  
                |                                    
           {Internet}
```

I have an internet setup like this. I can't change the IP address of the network A because I've so many devices connected to the network. I can pretty much change any settings on the router B. what should I do so that device on the both network can communicate with each other

Comment: Have you implemented static routing between network A and B? If not, please do.

Comment: I redrew your network diagram. Please double check it.

Comment: Questions - do you have (or are you likely to ever have)  more then 250 devices on your network? Are you statically allocating IP addresses out of A [without using DHCP to do so].- by this I mean is there anything stopping you from changing the netmask of devices behind router A?

Comment: Ladtly, are Aand B connected via ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a little more work, but another alternative would be to merge the two networks into a larger subnet.  This solution offers the advantage that Router B is no longer needed, and can be surplused to that "other project" you might have that needs a router.

```
           Network A                            Network  B

      PC1                PC2                PC3                PC4         
(192.168.1.100)    (192.168.1.101)    (192.168.0.100)    (192.168.0.101)
       |                  |                  |                  |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
                                    |     
                                 Router A 
                              (192.168.1.1)
                              255.255.254.0
                                    |                                  
                                    |                                    
                               {Internet}
```

In the DHCP settings on Router A, change the DHCP pool to be 192.168.0.0/23, or netmask 255.255.254.0 if your router prefers that notation.  All hosts on Network B will need to renew their DHCP leases to regain connectivity.  Network A hosts only need to change their netmask.

Also, if you have "too many devices" to renumber, you may want to look into DHCP reservations.  "Too many devices" is one sign that your network is beginning to outpace your management tools.  DHCP reservations makes it easy to have known, static IPs assigned to devices that need them, and still have the other network configuration components (netmask, default route, DNS resolvers, etc.) fluid and readily changeable.

Comment: Probably the easiest way. OP doesn't have to even change the current connectivity too much, just ensure that Router B and Router A are connected through LAN ports and IP addresses are handed out by only Router A. Router B will then act just as a switch.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the solution in it's simplest terms. Whether your equipment can support this or not, is another story.

1. Disable NAT on Router B
2. Create a static route on Router A:

> Dest Network: 192.168.0.0/24   Next Hop: `<The WAN Interface IP of Router B>`

3. Disable the Firewall on Router B, or enable firewall rules to allow communication between both networks.

Comment: I believe static routes are supported by almost every router in existance. Don't quote me on that though =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that:

- Router A is handing out DHCP addresses,
- Router A and B are typical home routers with:

  - one Internet port,
  - 4 LAN ports,
  - Wi-Fi,
  - and that you can access the configuration web page of both router A and B.

Do this:

- Find out the range of IP addresses in DHCP that Router A is handing out.  Pick 1 unused one.
- Plug cable from Router A to a LAN port in Router B (NOT Router B's Internet port).
- Access Router B's management page.

  - Change the router IP address to 192.168.1.254 with or other address that Router A's DHCP isn't handing out.  The subnet mask should be /24 or 255.255.255.0.
  - Turn OFF DHCP on Router B.
  - Disable everything you can on the Internet port, e.g. DHCP, etc.  You only want the LAN ports on this router.
  - Reboot all devices connected to router B.

The end result is that Router B is now just an access point and Ethernet switch, no longer doing any routing.  Router A is now handling all the routing and DHCP, so everything will be on 192.168.1.x/255.255.255.0.

Devices on router A's and B's Wi-Fi will be able to talk to each other and any wired devices, IF the "AP Isolation" feature is disabled.